# How to select <style type="text/css"> in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I would need to select the style element in the head of an html page and remove it from the dom, without using jquery.

Any idea how to do it?

---

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            p {
                color:blue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>A paragraph.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying this code with no success:

```
var styleSheetList = document.styleSheets;
document.styleSheets.length = 0;
console.log('+++ styleSheetList ELEMENT' + styleSheetList);
```

Comment: Is the HTML meant to be malformed?

Comment: you forget to close </style>.

Comment: my apologies I forgot to close the style tag, if you think appropriate please remove the down-votes, thanks for your help on this question

Comment: try google: "traversing dom in javascript"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.getElementsByTagName()` like this:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName( 'style' );
for( var i=els.length; i--; ) {
  els[i].parentNode.removeChild( els[i] );
}
```

Note, however, that removing the `<style>` element will *not* remove the styles it introduced!

Answer (score 0):

Get the hold of the `<style>` tag and then you need to select the parent to remove it from DOM. *(Assuming, Style tag is the second tag in HEAD after TITLE)*

```
var styleTag = document.getElementsByTagName("style");
var headTag = styleTag[0].parentNode;
headTag.removeChild(headTag.childNodes[1]);
```

The below code is generic, irrespective of the position of STYLE

```
var styleTag = document.getElementsByTagName("style");
var headTag = styleTag[0].parentNode;

for(var i=0; i<headTag.childNodes.length; i++)
{
    if(headTag.childNodes[i].nodeName === "STYLE")
        headTag.removeChild(headTag.childNodes[i]);
}
```